# When to unsubscribe from events in content views?

Tags: maui

I am making some reusable `ContentView` components in purely C#. In some cases, I want to subscribe to events to some of the elements I've added to the View. ie:

```
    public class MyEntry : ContentView
    {
        private readonly Entry _entry;
        public MyEntry()
        {
            _entry = new Entry();
            _entry.Focused += EntryFocused;
        }
        private void EntryFocused(object? sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            FocusCommand?.Execute(sender);
        }
    }
```

But I don't really see any `Dispose` method to override, or any other relevant lifecycle methods for that matter. So how should I properly unsubscribe from such events to avoid creating memory leaks?

If I change my class to inherit `IDisposable`, will the dispose method be called by the framework automatically?

Comment: Have you added `~MyEntry() => Dispose(false);`? With the usual `public void Dispose()` method that calls the protected `Dispose(bool disposing)` method.

Comment: @Jimi there is no Dispose method on ContentView. Also, I don't think the finalizer/destructor would work, as it will not be garbage collected while having a reference from the event handler.

Deleted my previous comment and posted again to fix some typos, as 5 minutes had passed and I could no longer edit.

Comment: The posting again with the same note: implement `IDisposable`, so you can at least call `Dispose()` yourself. Then test whether the finalizer is called or not when the top level container is destroyed

Comment: You mean you want to unsubscribe from the event `_entry.Focused`? You can unsubscribe it by `-=`.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I know how to do it. My question is about when to do it. How does the ContentView that it's no longer needed, if it doesn't implement IDisposable? If I choose to implement IDisposable, will the .NET MAUI framework take care of disposing it properly?

Comment: I posted the answer. I hope it is of assistance to you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to write my own logic to dispose of `IDisposable` views, which I manually call from my Navigation Service. If others read this and directly call the `Navigation` property on your content pages instead of using a `NavigationService` from your ViewModels, you'll have to find a way to hook into that.

In the NavigationService, I created this method:

```
private void DisposeChildElements(IView view)
{
    if (view is Layout layout)
    {
        foreach (var child in layout.Children)
        {
            DisposeChildElements(child);
            if (child is IDisposable disposable)
            {
                disposable.Dispose();
            }
        }
    } else if (view is IContentView {Content: View viewContent})
    {
        DisposeChildElements(viewContent);
    }

    if (view is IDisposable disposableView)
    {
        disposableView.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And then I call it in the GoBack method:

```
public async Task GoBackAsync()
{
    var currentPage = Shell.Current.CurrentPage;
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");

    if (currentPage != Shell.Current.CurrentPage)
    {
        if (currentPage is ContentPage contentPage)
            DisposeChildElements(contentPage.Content);
        if (currentPage is IAsyncDisposable asyncDisposable)
            await asyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
        else if (currentPage is IDisposable disposable)
            disposable.Dispose();

        if (currentPage.BindingContext is IAsyncDisposable vmAsyncDisposable)
            await vmAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync();
        else if (currentPage.BindingContext is IDisposable disposable)
            disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you also have a PopToRoot method in your NavigationService, you'd also need to implement something similar to call the same for all pages being removed.

Another thing to note: If you have any pages registered as Singletons in your DI, then you'll also need special handling for that. I don't use Singleton pages, so it's not something I had to solve, but if I were to implement it, I'd just make an `ISingletonPage` interface and inherit from it on your singleton pages. Then in `GoBackAsync`, I'd check if the page is `ISingletonPage` and skip the disposal if it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1**

> My question is about when to do it. How does the ContentView that it's no longer needed, if it doesn't implement IDisposable?

You can add this to your MyEntry:

```cs
~MyEntry() 
{
    _entry.Focused -= EntryFocused;
}
```

**Q2**

> If I choose to implement IDisposable, will the .NET MAUI framework take care of disposing it properly?

You have to do it manually. Javier Suarez answered this question with a [YouTube comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8d7xLErPm9o&lc=UgzXYwxHY79uanaQVTF4AaABAg&ab_channel=JavierSu%C3%A1rez) under his video. For more info you can refer to [Using ContentView](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/ways-create-netmaui-controls#3-using-contentview) and [the code sample for Dispose](https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/ways-create-netmaui-controls/blob/main/src/CreateControls/Controls/CustomControls/ContentViewCheckBox.cs#L67).

Comment: Q1: Can you elaborate on why it would be useful to use the finalizer to unsubscribe events? As far as I dunderstand, the object is not eligible for garbage collection while the event handler is active, and as such, the finalizer will not be called.

Comment: Q2: That's disappointing. So when popping a page from my navigation stack, I have to recursively iterate all children of all elements to find which ones implement `IDisposable` so I can call the `Dispose` method to free up resources?

Comment: Q1: Yes, you are right. I mean you can use finalizer to ensure that events are unsubscribed when GC start. Q2: Yes, you have to do. Here is another code sample: [ClockViewModel](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/7.0/XAML/Fundamentals/XamlSamples/ViewModels/ClockViewModel.cs#L31).

Comment: I did some testing, and I didn't ever see the finalizer being called, so I'm not a great fan of using it for event unsubscription. As far as I can read, you should avoid using finalizers to clean up resources if at all possible. Read more under `Finalization` here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2000/november/garbage-collection-automatic-memory-management-in-the-microsoft-net-framework